# Toggle boolean field in Firestore using FieldValue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm currently trying to create a toggle function for a Firestore boolean field.
I would like to know if there is any way to toggle this boolean field directly via the .update() function, and avoid having to .get() that field's original value beforehand.

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).update({
    field: !field
});
```

I know **Firebase's FieldValue** actually helps avoiding that extra .get() call, and I thought FieldValue.isEqual() could maybe help me but what It does is comparing that field to another, not comparing itself to false, which is what I actually need:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).update({
    field: admin.firestore.FieldValue.isEqual(false)
});
```

Comment: You cannot change a boolean value without reading it first. When it comes to incrementation and you're using `FieldValue.increment(x)`, nobody cares what is the actual value on the server, while when you want to negate a boolean value, you have to know it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Since toggling the value means that you need to know the current value of the field, there is no way to do this in a single operation. Instead you will need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to first read the document, and then write the modified field value back atomically.